# Как убрать лишний background при активном слайде в навигации Slick slider?

Tags: html, css, slider-slick.js

При активном слайде, в маркере отображается белый бэкграунд, который я задавал для неактивных слайдов, как сделать так, чтобы он исчезал на активном слайде?

Весь код jsfiddle.net/mpvow81d/

Сам сайт ilyin1ib.beget.tech

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.slick-dots li button {
    height: 4px !important;
    padding: 4px !important;
    width: 20px !important;
    background: #fff!important;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

li.slick-active {
    width: 40px !important;
    height:100% !important;
    background: @orange !important;
    z-index:99 !important;
    transition: 0.3s;
}


.slick-dots li button:before {
  display:none;
}


.slick-dots {
  bottom: 100px !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте дописать в css

```
 .slick-dots li.slick-active button{
  background-color:transparent!important;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]